# How should I store data in a matrix from my simulation study?

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, logistic-regression, montecarlo

Im currently doing a monte carlo-simulation where Im testing which model is the best for variable selection. When doing so I need to store the information from each simulation in a matrix so that I can later analyse it. As a newbie to R Im having difficulties executing this task.
Here´s the relevant code:

```
iter <- 2000

results.matrix <- matrix(ncol = 12, nrow = iter )

for (i in iter) {
  Ylink <- (1 * (age - mean(age)) + (1.5 * (gender == "1")) + 1.2 * (inkomst - mean(inkomst)))
  Yprob <- 1/(1 + exp(-Ylink))
  Y <- rbinom(2000, size = 1, prob = Yprob)
  df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, age, gender, inkomst, Y)
  glm0 <- glm(Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + age + gender + inkomst, data = df)
  summary(glm0)
  results.matrix[,1] <- summary(glm0)$coef[, "Pr(>|t|)"]
}
```

When trying this following error comes up: "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
iter <- 2000

results.matrix <- matrix(ncol = 12, nrow = iter )

for (i in seq_len(iter)) {
  Ylink <- (1 * (age - mean(age)) + (1.5 * (gender == "1")) + 1.2 * (inkomst - mean(inkomst)))
  Yprob <- 1/(1 + exp(-Ylink))
  Y <- rbinom(2000, size = 1, prob = Yprob)
  df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, age, gender, inkomst, Y)
  glm0 <- glm(Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + age + gender + inkomst, data = df)
  results.matrix[i,] <- summary(glm0)$coef[, "Pr(>|t|)"]
}
```

Comment: I tried that and the following error code came up: Error in results.matrix[i, ] <- summary(glm0)$coef[, "Pr(>|t|)"] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @kevinsingh13 It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).